# subscribeOn has no effect when creating new Observables

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java, observable, rx-java2

As shown below, I am creating Observables. but when I specify the thread on which the observables to be processed ".subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())", the code shows
no output. but when i omit it i receive the results normally.

please let me know why

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())//newThread
```

does not work with .just operator and when creating Observables

**code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<List<Person>> observables = Observable.create(e-> {
        for(List<Person> p : Main.getPersons()) {
            e.onNext(p);
            System.out.println("onNext called");
        }
        e.onComplete();
    });
    observables
    //.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())//newThread
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .map(p->p.get(0).getName()+"..map operator")
    .subscribe(new Observer() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onCompleted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Object arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onNextFromObserver: " + arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }); 
}

private static List<List<Person>> getPersons() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(new Person("Sanna", 59, "EGY")),
            Arrays.asList(new Person("Mohamed", 69, "EGY")),
            Arrays.asList(new Person("Ahmed", 44, "QTR")),
                    Arrays.asList(new Person("Fatma", 29, "KSA")),
                    Arrays.asList(new Person("Lobna", 24, "EGY"))
                    );
}
}
```

Comment: When you say "shows no output", how are you subscribing? If you subscribe in a test method, and then exit the method, there will likely be no output because the `io` thread may not have time to be invoked.

Comment: @BobDalgleish i am subscribing as you saw in the code above..and i am not in test mode at all i am making som eexamples in eclipse

Comment: `subscribe()` is called on the `main` thread. `subscribeOn()` moves the subscription over on to the `io` thread. Meanwhile, the `main()` method has terminated, and any other threads won't have a chance to execute. Add `Thread.sleep(1000);` after the subscription to see the difference.

Comment: @BobDalgleish but also in subscribeOn i used newThread ..but i dont receive any output either

Comment: Please read the relevant [Getting started](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#simple-background-computation) section. Then read further on so it can answer your subsequent questions.